# Linkedin Lead Gen Forms webhook API

Tags: linkedin-api

I did not find the webhook of LinkedIn. Please provide the API to set up a webhook in the ads form.

the API I found is [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation?context=linkedin/context.)

but I did not find the Linkedin Lead Gen Forms webhook API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this? 
[Lead Notification Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-gen/ads-leadgen#lead-notification-webhooks)